# Read specific data from a webpage source code, displaying it in web form after customization

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Here Two portion of my own website source code. Now i want to find  "title="View all posts by " from source code and want to show the last all character before the " ends.**

```
<span class="posted-on"><a href="https://pickleballconsumer.com/?p=100" title="5:17 pm" rel="bookmark"><time class="updated" datetime="2018-09-24T18:57:50+00:00" itemprop="dateModified">September 24, 2018</time><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-09-24T17:17:10+00:00" itemprop="datePublished">September 24, 2018</time></a></span> <span class="byline"><span class="author vcard" itemprop="author" itemtype="https://schema.org/Person" itemscope>by <a class="url fn n" href="https://pickleballconsumer.com/?author=1" title="View all posts by Sampgoogly" rel="author" itemprop="url"><span class="author-name" itemprop="name">Sampgoogly</span></a></span></span> </div><!-- .entry-meta --> <header class="entry-header"> <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="https://pickleballconsumer.com/?p=183" rel="bookmark">fdsafdsfsfsfsdf</a></h2> <div class="entry-meta"> <span class="posted-on"><a href="https://pickleballconsumer.com/?p=183" title="5:09 pm" rel="bookmark"><time class="updated" datetime="2019-03-27T17:09:24+00:00" itemprop="dateModified">March 27, 2019</time><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2019-03-27T17:09:17+00:00" itemprop="datePublished">March 27, 2019</time></a></span> <span class="byline"><span class="author vcard" itemprop="author" itemtype="https://schema.org/Person" itemscope>by <a class="url fn n" href="https://pickleballconsumer.com/?author=2" title="View all posts by admin" rel="author" itemprop="url"><span class="author-name" itemprop="name">admin</span></a></span></span> </div><!-- .entry-meta
-->
```

========================================================================

For an example in 1st code  title="View all posts by Sampgoogly" so here i  want to catch the Sampgoogly word and to show it in my webform. In second Code "title="View all posts by admin"  i want to show the string "admin" which is after view all posts by word and want to show in my dot net web form. How can i do that please help me with code.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you tried?

Comment: hi I tried this :